# How to test ConstraintViolationException with assertJ?

Tags: validation, testing, assertj, constraintviolationexception

If I have a bean like

```
@Data
@Validated
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Document(collection = "Xxx")
public class XxxDocument extends Zzz {
    @Min(0)
    @Max(255)
    private Integer aProperty;
}
```

How can I write a test using assertJ that checks whether the setting of `aProperty` raised a `ConstraintViolationException`? I would like to use Lombok's `@Data` annotation to avoid writing the getters and setters where I could declare that the setter throws this exception.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with AssertJ and some manual work, but [`assertj-bean-validation`](https://github.com/jinahya/assertj-bean-validation) might be a better candidate for it.

Answer (score 0):

As @StefanoCordio mentioned, with [`assertj-bean-validation`](https://github.com/jinahya/assertj-bean-validation), you can do this.

```java
XxxDocument document = new XxxDocument(-1);

assertThatBean(document).isValid();                     // should fail
assertThatBean(document).hasValidProperty("aProperty"); // should fail

assertThatProperty(0).isValidFor(XxxDocument.class, "aProperty");
```